# SharePoint code working in Console but not in Web API

Tags: c#, sharepoint, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I added the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll into a **console** application and have written some SharePoint code, i can see the results on the console, but when I created a **Web API** project and added the same code, its throwing the error. Any idea what I am missing? Does Web API support SharePoint or tweaks have to done?

**Console Application:**
Able to get the count of alerts on the site
[image: Console project with Microsoft.SharePoint.dll]

**Web API Application:**
Getting error here...
[image: Web API project with Microsoft.SharePoint.dll]

**Update1**: Hosted the Console and Web API app in the same server where SharePoint is installed. Null reference is for the SPWeb object.

**Update2**: Not all the values of SPSite and SPWeb objects are not filled with SharePoint data. Some values like SPSite Id are returned, but not all.

*"Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."*

[image]

Comment: Related: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: A few questions. Is it the `web` or the `Alerts` object that is null?  How do you authenticate the API?

Comment: The second update is irrelevant - if you try to enumerate eg. AllWebs the delay is so large the debugger times out and refuses to display the rest of the methods. That doesn't mean they are empty

Comment: Does your *application pool identity* have permission to this site? Why do you use the server-side SDK instead of the client-side SDK anyway?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Didnt work with the client side SDK, I have few questions. 1 - How can we use Client side SDK with Web API. 2- Any issue which would come across if we use Client side SDK?

Comment: @krishna `didn't work` isn't a helpful problem description.

Comment: @krishna you should use client SDK because: 1. your code is not hosted in SharePoint 2. not using it causes problems as you can see.

Comment: @JanVanek I would have gone with Client SDK if it supports SharePoint Alerts, but I am afraid it doesn't. Any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by placing SharePoint Server side code in

`RunWithElevatedPrivileges`

and using the **same Application Pool Identity** which is being used to run the SharePoint Web Application.